# LWJGL Display crashing when implemented with Jframe and canvas

Tags: java, swing, opengl, jframe, lwjgl

I'm working on creating a 2D Java game with a lighting engine with OpenGL using LWJGL, but I've hit a wall when trying to link up keyboard inputs.

The render loop works fine, but as soon as I tried to implement a JFrame/canvas and the getParent/KeyListener combo The application crashes immediately after starting up.
I have to shut the application down in netbeans - the window doesn't respond to right clicking application's entry in the start toolbar.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Main main = new Main();
  main.run();

}

public void run() {
  initialize();
  //animLoop();
}

private void initialize() {
  try {
    Frame theFrame = new Frame("Inlight");
    Canvas theCanvas = new Canvas();
    theCanvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(windowWidth, windowHeight));
    theFrame.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    theCanvas.requestFocusInWindow();

    theFrame.add(theCanvas);

    theFrame.setVisible(true);
    //before doing the following, I need to create the canvas within which openGL does it's rendering 
    //create it before applying keylistener

    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(windowWidth, windowHeight));
    Display.setParent(theCanvas);
    Display.getParent().addKeyListener(new InlightKeyListener());
    Display.create(new PixelFormat(0, 16, 1));

  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
  fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  StringBuilder fragmentShaderSource = new StringBuilder();

  try {
    String line;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/shader.frag"));
    //points to the shader doc
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      fragmentShaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {}

  glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
  glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
  if (glGetShaderi(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
    System.err.println("Fragment shader not compiled!");
  }

  glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
  glValidateProgram(shaderProgram);


  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(0, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, 1, -1);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

  glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
  glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  System.out.println("Done initialize");
}

public synchronized void animLoop() {
  //This method will loop the render
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  //sets the starting time to the current time
  long curTime = startTime;
  //The current time measurement, so at thestart the curTime = starting time  
  while (curTime - startTime < 1800) {
    long timePassed = System.currentTimeMillis() - curTime;
    //Makes the timePassed variable equal to the System's current time - the last measured current time.
    curTime += timePassed;
    //updates the measurement of the current time to the actual current time. (I imagine some small amount to time is lost while it is updated. this is negligible.)
    organiseTitle();
    //sets up the ojects to display the title screen for 1800 milliseconds
    render();
    //draws the new screen scene to the display
    clearObj();
    //cleans up the items built for that last render
  }

  while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
    long timePassed = System.currentTimeMillis() - curTime;
    //Makes the timePassed variable equal to the System's current time - the last measured current time.
    curTime += timePassed;
    //updates the measurement of the current time to the actual current time. (I imagine some small amount to time is lost while it is updated. this is negligible.)
    Organiselevel1(20, 200);
    render();
    //draws the new screen scene to the display
    clearObj();
    //cleans up the items built for that last render
  }
  glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
  glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
  Display.destroy();
  //closes the window
}
```

//There's more code after this point of course, but it's all already been tested and works.

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: no, it just crashes immediately after the Sout prints "Done initialize". I have to stop the process in the IDE for it to even close the window.

Comment: Do you call Display.update() anywhere in your code? This handles the window events, so if you don't call it, you won't be able to close or move the window at all.

Comment: Yep, at the end of my render(); module called in the animLoop method, along with Display.sync(60);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh god I only just realized the call to my main loop was commented out.

/facepalm